# Zsh, directory tab-completion with prefix

Tags: zsh, tab-completion, prefix

I have a directory where I put all my projects in, let's say it's `~/projects` as an example. I've made a command called `s` which takes one argument, and moves me into that directory. E.g.: `s foo` moves me to `~/projects/foo`.

What I'd like is to have a completion command of some sorts, which would act like `cd` so I could do keep hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> to go further into the `~/projects/...` directories.

Basically, `cd` with a prefix which is always present.

I've looked into zstyle completion in `man zshcompsys`, but realized I just don't know enough about it to understand it properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example from [my own `.zshrc`](https://github.com/mscharley/dotfiles) that I keep as a copy/paste snippet:

```
# Try using the below template to set up zsh functions that act
# as aliases to cd and allow you to get autocomplete nicely.

project() { cd /path/to/project/$1; }
compctl -W /path/to/project/ -/ project
```

Just edit the `/path/to/project` section in both lines above then you are good to go.

Comment: This works great, thank you! A lot simpler than I would have thought.

Comment: For the 'oh-my-zsh` case insensitive completion, make sure to add
`-M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'`, i.e.

`compctl -M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' -W /path/to/project/ -/ project`

Answer (score 3):

A different way of achieving a similar effect is to define aliases for directories:

```
setopt auto_cd
alias -d s=~/projects
```

Type `~s/` <kbd>Tab</kbd> to change to a subdirectory of `~/projects`; you can use `~s` in a command argument, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an entry directly to the named directory hash table:

```
hash -d s="${HOME}/projects"
```

Now you can simply use `~s` to refer to your directory, and you can use Tab-completion in a `cd` command:  cd ~s/<kbd>Tab</kbd>

If you have zsh's `autocd` option set, you can leave out the `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `CDPATH`:

```
export CDPATH="$CDPATH:$HOME/Repositories:$HOME/Repositories/jc/Projects"
```

Now you can access all subdirectories within the specified directories from every other directory as if they would be the subdirectories of the current directory:

```
➜  ~ /tmp
➜  /tmp pwd
/tmp
➜  /tmp MyAwesomeProject 
~/Repositories/jc/Projects/MyAwesomeProject
➜  MyAwesomeProject git:(master) pwd
/Users/rafael/Repositories/jc/Projects/MyAwesomeProject
➜  MyAwesomeProject git:(master)
```